# Why `apt-get purge` keeps trying to install things for me?

Tags: linux, java, apt-get, apt, raspbian

I try to purge the Oracle Java 8 JDK on Raspbian Stretch:

```
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java8-jdk
```

But it keeps trying to install replacements for me. For example, it keeps telling me "the following NEW packages will be installed":

```
ca-certificates-java default-java-plugin default-jre default-jre-headless 
icedtea-8-plugin icedtea-netx icedtea-netx-common
libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni openjdk-8-jre 
openjdk-8-jre-headless oracle-java7-jdk
```

I have tried adding the flag `--no-install-recommends`. The install list gets shorter, but still includes those seemingly JDK/JRE replacements:

```
ca-certificates-java default-jre default-jre-headless libatk-wrapper-java 
libatk-wrapper-java-jni openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless 
oracle-java7-jdk
```

Is there a way to stop it from installing those? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe something else needs them?

Answer (score 0):

You should try `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge oracle-java8-jdk`, il will :

1. Remove `oracle-java8-jdk`
2. Remove all the dependencies of this packet (`ca-certificates-java default-java-plugin`, etc etc...)
3. Remove all files of these packets